# Updating day number columns' values in Ledger_stat table using dynamic update query

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I have a table `LEDGER_STAT_DLY` in which we've columns for each day in a month *(`DAY_01` is for day 1, `DAY_02`,...., DAY_31)*. Currently, I am using case statements to update values of `Day` column as following.

```
CASE DAY(V_DATE)
                WHEN 1 THEN
                UPDATE /*+ index(a LEDGER_STAT_DLY_IDX02_IN) */ LEDGER_STAT_DLY A
                    SET DAY_01 =  NVL(DAY_01,0) + NVL(V_AMOUNT,0)
                    WHERE IDENTITY_CODE =  NVL(V_IDENTITY_CODE,0)
                            AND YEAR_S =  NVL(V_YEAR_S,0)
                            AND MONTH_NO = NVL(V_MONTH,0)
                            AND CONSOLIDATION_CD =  NVL(V_CONSOLIDATION_CD,0)
                            AND FINANCIAL_ELEM_ID = NVL(V_FINANCIAL_ELEM_ID,0)
                            AND ORG_UNIT_ID   = NVL(V_ORG_UNIT_ID,0)
                            AND GL_ACCOUNT_ID = NVL(V_GL_ACCOUNT_ID,0)
                            AND COMMON_COA_ID = NVL(V_COMMON_COA_ID,0)
                            AND PRODUCT_1_ID  = NVL(V_PRODUCT_1_ID,0)
                            AND PRODUCT_ID    = NVL(V_PRODUCT_ID,0)
                            AND PRODUCT_3_ID  = NVL(V_PRODUCT_3_ID,0)
                            AND COST_TYPE_ID    = NVL(V_MEMO_GL_ACCOUNT_ID,0)
                            AND BALANCE_TYPE_CD = NVL(V_BALANCE_TYPE_CD,0);

                WHEN 2 THEN
                UPDATE /*+ index(a LEDGER_STAT_DLY_IDX02_IN) */ LEDGER_STAT_DLY A
                    SET DAY_02 =  NVL(DAY_02,0) + NVL(V_AMOUNT,0)
                    WHERE IDENTITY_CODE =  NVL(V_IDENTITY_CODE,0)
                            AND YEAR_S =  NVL(V_YEAR_S,0)
                            AND MONTH_NO = NVL(V_MONTH,0)
                            AND CONSOLIDATION_CD =  NVL(V_CONSOLIDATION_CD,0)
                            AND FINANCIAL_ELEM_ID = NVL(V_FINANCIAL_ELEM_ID,0)
                            AND ORG_UNIT_ID   = NVL(V_ORG_UNIT_ID,0)
                            AND GL_ACCOUNT_ID = NVL(V_GL_ACCOUNT_ID,0)
                            AND COMMON_COA_ID = NVL(V_COMMON_COA_ID,0)
                            AND PRODUCT_1_ID  = NVL(V_PRODUCT_1_ID,0)
                            AND PRODUCT_ID    = NVL(V_PRODUCT_ID,0)
                            AND PRODUCT_3_ID  = NVL(V_PRODUCT_3_ID,0)
                            AND COST_TYPE_ID    = NVL(V_MEMO_GL_ACCOUNT_ID,0)
                            AND BALANCE_TYPE_CD = NVL(V_BALANCE_TYPE_CD,0);

-- and so forth, I have written 31 blocks
```

Although it is working fine, the code in the procedure, is super long. Could you please suggest how I can update it using dynamic query so this code reduces to fewer lines/single block instead of 31 separate case statements.
Thanks in advance for kind help!

PS: day is being extracted from `V_DATE` using `day()` function. Logic is, whenever `day(v_date)` matches `day_number(01, 02,03...)` column of `LEDGER_STAT_DLY` table, update value for that column accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the sentiment expressed in Bob Jarvis's answer, but if refactoring the underlying table is not an option for you, this can be done with dynamic SQL.

It looks like there is one variable(the `DAY_01`/`DAY_02`/`DAY_03`... field) that needs to be used in two places in your provided example.  So this field will need to be replaced into the rest of the static statement.

An example is below.

First, add a variable to hold the target field name.  (This isn't really required, just for readability).

Since there is an orderly transformation in the existing switch between the day-number 1,2,3 and the field `DAY_01`, `DAY_02`, `DAY_03`, this can be determined in a direct assignment.

Then in the procedure body where the switch is currently in-use, you can use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, replacing (via concatentation or a string formatter like `UTL_LMS`) the column-name in the statement with the target `DAY_01`,`DAY_02` etc. where the column-name is in the statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_LEDGER_STAT_DLY(V_IDENTITY_CODE NUMBER,
                                                   V_CONSOLIDATION_CD NUMBER,
                                                   V_FINANCIAL_ELEM_ID NUMBER,
                                                   V_ORG_UNIT_ID NUMBER,
                                                   V_GL_ACCOUNT_ID NUMBER,
                                                   V_COMMON_COA_ID NUMBER,
                                                   V_PRODUCT_1_ID NUMBER,
                                                   V_PRODUCT_ID NUMBER,
                                                   V_PRODUCT_3_ID NUMBER,
                                                   V_DATE DATE,
                                                   V_AMOUNT NUMBER,
                                                   V_MEMO_GL_ACCOUNT_ID NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
                                                   V_POSTINGTYPE CHAR DEFAULT 'N',
                                                   V_BALANCE_TYPE_CD NUMBER DEFAULT 0)
    IS

    V_CNT    NUMBER;
    V_D      NUMBER;
    V_DAY    CHAR(6);
    V_MONTH  CHAR(2);
    V_MO     NUMBER;
    V_YEAR_S NUMBER;

BEGIN

    IF V_POSTINGTYPE = 'N' THEN

        IF NVL(V_AMOUNT, 0) <> 0 THEN

            V_MO := (MONTH(V_DATE));
            V_MONTH := LPAD(V_MO, 2, '0');
            V_YEAR_S := (YEAR(V_DATE));
            V_D := (DAY(V_DATE));
            V_DAY := 'DAY_' || lpad(V_D, 2, '0');


            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE('UPDATE /*+ index(a LEDGER_STAT_DLY_IDX02_IN) */ LEDGER_STAT_DLY A
                           SET %s =  NVL(%s,0) + NVL(:THE_AMOUNT,0)
                           WHERE IDENTITY_CODE =  NVL(:THE_IDENTITY_CODE,0)
                              AND YEAR_S =  NVL(:THE_YEAR_S,0)
                              AND MONTH_NO = NVL(:THE_MONTH,0)
                              AND CONSOLIDATION_CD =  NVL(:THE_CONSOLIDATION_CD,0)
                              AND FINANCIAL_ELEM_ID = NVL(:THE_FINANCIAL_ELEM_ID,0)
                              AND ORG_UNIT_ID   = NVL(:ORG_UNIT_ID,0)
                              AND GL_ACCOUNT_ID = NVL(:THE_GL_ACCOUNT_ID,0)
                              AND COMMON_COA_ID = NVL(:THE_COMMON_COA_ID,0)
                              AND PRODUCT_1_ID  = NVL(:THE_PRODUCT_1_ID,0)
                              AND PRODUCT_ID    = NVL(:THE_PRODUCT_ID,0)
                              AND PRODUCT_3_ID  = NVL(:THE_PRODUCT_3_ID,0)
                              AND COST_TYPE_ID    = NVL(:THE_MEMO_GL_ACCOUNT_ID,0)
                              AND BALANCE_TYPE_CD = NVL(:THE_BALANCE_TYPE_CD,0)', V_DAY, V_DAY)
                USING V_AMOUNT, V_IDENTITY_CODE, V_YEAR_S, V_MONTH, V_CONSOLIDATION_CD,
                V_FINANCIAL_ELEM_ID, V_ORG_UNIT_ID, V_GL_ACCOUNT_ID,
                V_COMMON_COA_ID, V_PRODUCT_1_ID, V_PRODUCT_ID, V_PRODUCT_3_ID, V_MEMO_GL_ACCOUNT_ID, V_BALANCE_TYPE_CD;

        END IF;

    END IF;

END;
/
```

Comment: I am getting error SQL command not properly ended error. Could you please confirm/spot error, if there is any. I am testing it at my end as well.

Comment: Thanks @SachinSharma.  That was probably a trailing semi-colon in the dynamic statement (my fault cutting/pasting from the example).  It has been removed in the example here.  Can you let me know if that corrects the error for you?

Comment: Now it is throwing 'V_BALANCE_TYPE_CD' is invalid identifier error. I am passing it in procedure and then using it in this query.  for reference, I've posted full proc here ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57045175/ora-01747-invalid-user-table-column-table-column-or-column-specification-erro```

Comment: Thanks @SachinSharma.  I was under the impression from the accepted answer that you had decided to refactor as Bob Jarvis suggested and set aside the procedure here?  I would avoid further troubleshooting if there is not an active problem.  Is this still an ongoing problem?

Comment: Yes, I am getting 'V_BALANCE_TYPE_CD' and all other columns such as V_MEMO_GL_ACCOUNT_ID, etc. as  invalid identifier. This is the  parameter I am passing in procedure, as you may have seen in procedure mentioned in above link. Could you please suggest what should be updated in your query. Also, I'm not familiar with this format so it'll be great help if you can guide me in this

Comment: Thanks @SachinSharma.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57045175/ora-01747-invalid-user-table-column-table-column-or-column-specification-erro is not using dynamic sql in the same manner as here.  Bind variables cannot be used for identifiers -- they must (sort of) be raw text in the dynamic sql string.  In the example here, I used string replacements, not binds.  But I'm still not sure if this question is open.  Did you decide to just refactor as Bob Jarvis suggested?

Comment: I can not do this. Someone else from other team has created table in this way and they said it is needed in this format for some other business reasons so I believe I have to get a way around to get it updated. Dynamic query is causing weird issues. Could you please suggest some sample changes which are needed to make it work so i can start working in that direction and get it working.

Comment: Could you please suggest why I am getting 'V_BALANCE_TYPE_CD' invalid identifier error when using your query in which you are using string replacements. Could you please suggest some updates?

Comment: ```                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE('UPDATE /*+ index(a LEDGER_STAT_DLY_IDX02_IN) */ LEDGER_STAT_DLY A
                           SET %s =  NVL(%s,0) + NVL(V_AMOUNT,0)
                           WHERE IDENTITY_CODE =  NVL(V_IDENTITY_CODE,0)
                              AND YEAR_S =  NVL(V_YEAR_S,0)
                              AND MONTH_NO = NVL(V_MONTH,0)',V_TARGET_COLUMN, V_TARGET_COLUMN);```

Comment: I've taken out other variables. Above query is also throwing error 'V_MONTH' is invalid identifier. I ma not sure why. Could you please suggest the possible reason?

Comment: Thanks @SachinSharma.  I'll update this example to include the extra params instead of commenting that they would be required.

Comment: @SachinSharma, ok the example here has been updated as in the other linked procedure (I didn't include the other insert, etc. though).  Does this get at the problem you are seeing now?  Thanks

Comment: ```ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist
ORA-06512: at "USB.POST_DAILY_LEDGER", line 311
ORA-06512: at "USB.POST_DAILY_LEDGER", line 188```

Comment: It's resolved. V_ORG_UNIT_ID was repeated twice hence binding issue was popping up. It's working now. Thanks for kind help!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196493/discussion-between-sachin-sharma-and-alexgibbs).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, but your best bet is to normalize this table, getting rid of the repeated `DAY_01`, `DAY_02`, etc fields. This will make your job very much simpler.

Apparently your table currently looks something like

```
CREATE TABLE LEDGER_STAT_DLY 
  (IDENTITY_CODE      NUMBER,
   YEAR_S             NUMBER,
   MONTH_NO           NUMBER,
   CONSOLIDATION_CD   NUMBER,
   FINANCIAL_ELEM_ID  NUMBER,
   ORG_UNIT_ID        NUMBER,
   GL_ACCOUNT_ID      NUMBER,
   COMMON_COA_ID      NUMBER,
   PRODUCT_ID         NUMBER,
   PRODUCT_1_ID       NUMBER,
   PRODUCT_3_ID       NUMBER,
   COST_TYPE_ID       NUMBER,
   BALANCE_TYPE_CD    NUMBER,
   DAY_01             NUMBER,
   DAY_02             NUMBER,
   ...
   DAY_31             NUMBER);
```

I suggest replacing this with

```
CREATE TABLE LEDGER_STAT_DLY 
  (IDENTITY_CODE      NUMBER,
   YEAR_S             NUMBER,
   MONTH_NO           NUMBER,
   CONSOLIDATION_CD   NUMBER,
   FINANCIAL_ELEM_ID  NUMBER,
   ORG_UNIT_ID        NUMBER,
   GL_ACCOUNT_ID      NUMBER,
   COMMON_COA_ID      NUMBER,
   PRODUCT_ID         NUMBER,
   PRODUCT_1_ID       NUMBER,
   PRODUCT_3_ID       NUMBER,
   COST_TYPE_ID       NUMBER,
   BALANCE_TYPE_CD    NUMBER,
   DAY_NUMBER         NUMBER,
   DAY_VALUE          NUMBER);
```

`DAY_NUMBER` becomes the number of the day within the month, so it has the values 1 - 31. `DAY_VALUE` is assigned the values which used to go into DAY_01, DAY_02, etc. If you think about all the places where you're writing blocks of repeated code to handle all the individual DAY_xx fields you'll realize how much this easier this normalized structure will be to deal with.