# Invalid identifier error for v_MONTH in dynamic query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm running following procedure inside a package to post entries in table ledger_stat_dly.
I've written dynamic query to replace case statements but I am facing following error.
Could you please suggest why `V_Month is invalid identifier` error popping up while it is defined properly in procedure.
Thanks in advance for help.

```
Error is:
ORA-00904: "V_MONTH": invalid identifier
```

```
    (
        V_IDENTITY_CODE      NUMBER,    
        V_CONSOLIDATION_CD   NUMBER,    
        V_FINANCIAL_ELEM_ID  NUMBER,    
        V_ORG_UNIT_ID        NUMBER,   
        V_GL_ACCOUNT_ID      NUMBER,    
        V_COMMON_COA_ID      NUMBER,   
        V_PRODUCT_1_ID       NUMBER,   
        V_PRODUCT_ID         NUMBER,   
        V_PRODUCT_3_ID       NUMBER,    
        V_DATE               DATE,        
        V_AMOUNT             NUMBER,    
        V_MEMO_GL_ACCOUNT_ID NUMBER DEFAULT 0,  
        V_POSTINGTYPE        CHAR DEFAULT 'N', 
        V_BALANCE_TYPE_CD    NUMBER DEFAULT 0 
)
IS

V_CNT NUMBER;
V_MONTH CHAR(2);
V_MO NUMBER;
V_YEAR_S NUMBER;

-- variables store result of dynamic cursor
V_SL   VARCHAR2(2500);
V_TARGET_COLUMN VARCHAR2(6 CHAR);

BEGIN              


   IF V_POSTINGTYPE = 'N' THEN

        IF NVL(V_AMOUNT,0) <> 0  THEN

                V_MO := (MONTH(V_DATE));
                V_MONTH := LPAD(V_MO,2,'0');
                V_YEAR_S := (YEAR(V_DATE));
                V_TARGET_COLUMN := CONCAT('DAY_',LPAD(TO_CHAR(DAY(V_DATE)),2,'0'));              

                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE('UPDATE /*+ index(a LEDGER_STAT_DLY_IDX02_IN) */ LEDGER_STAT_DLY A
                           SET %s =  NVL(%s,0) + NVL(V_AMOUNT,0)
                           WHERE IDENTITY_CODE =  NVL(V_IDENTITY_CODE,0)
                              AND YEAR_S =  NVL(V_YEAR_S,0)
                              AND MONTH_NO = NVL(V_MONTH,0)',V_TARGET_COLUMN, V_TARGET_COLUMN);


        END IF; 

    END IF;  --CLOSURE FOR POSTING TYPE IF STATEMENT



END IN_LEDGER_STAT_DAILY;
```

Comment: Run the query displayed by "DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_sl is: '||V_SL)" and then post the errors generated by that.  Post the values of the first set of bind variables too.

Comment: Can't post entire query here because of word limit here but I'm getting same query in dbms_output what is in V_SL and error is same

Comment: Bind variables can't be used for identifiers.

Comment: @alexgibbs: Could you please suggest what is the error here. I've updated code but following  is the error. ```ORA-01747: invalid user name.table namecolumn name``` Sorry if it's basic but i believe my brain isn't working any more in it.

Comment: What was value of V_TARGET_COLUMN?  Does it match the name of a column in LEDGER_STAT_DLY?

Comment: Yes, it does. Column name in table is ```DAY_30```. I've been working on it for a while and  I've updated question to ask current issue. Looking forward to suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you composed the SQL statement as a string the PLSQL engine does NOT substituted for the variable name (their just part of a literal string), therefore the SQL engine sees the string 'V_MONTH' but there is no column by that name thus invalid identifier. If you stay with dynamic SQL you'll have to do value substitution yourself. The same also applies to the other variables. So:

```
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE(
  'UPDATE /*+ index(a LEDGER_STAT_DLY_IDX02_IN) */ LEDGER_STAT_DLY A
      SET %s =  NVL(%s,0) + NVL(%s ,0)
    WHERE IDENTITY_CODE =  NVL(%s ,0)
      AND YEAR_S =  NVL(%s ,0)
      AND MONTH_NO = NVL(%s ,0)'
     ,V_TARGET_COLUMN, V_TARGET_COLUMN ,V_AMOUNT,V_IDENTITY_CODE,V_YEAR_S,V_MONTH);
```

You may also need to do any necessary format conversions.